# how to use recyclerview's adapter class in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I've a list which is rendered from retrofit2 in previous activity,i've to set it to recyclerview's adapter.Adapter class is used in fragment class,Here is my code,
I'm not sure that I'm doing in a right way. please help....

```
package com.group.visioncare;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.group.visioncare.BaseClasses.BaseClass;
import com.group.visioncare.PojoClasses.OrderModel;
import com.group.visioncare.RestInterfaces.AVCEndPointInterface;

import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class FragmentActivity extends Fragment {

    List<OrderModel> ordersList1;
    List<OrderModel> ordersList2;

    public String apiURL = BaseClass.getApiURL();
    AVCEndPointInterface avcService;

    String order_status;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    OrdersAdapter mAdapter;        

    public FragmentActivity(List<OrderModel> OrdersList) {            
        this.ordersList1 = OrderList;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentactivity, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new OrdersAdapter(ordersList1);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    class OrdersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrdersAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        public List<OrderModel> ordersModelList;

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            TextView Order_no, Order_Date, Sub_name, Sub_mobileno, Sub_billno, Sub_age, Sub_emailid, Order_status, Itemstatus;

            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

                Order_no = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.orderno_txtvw);
                Order_Date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_txtvw);
                Sub_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subname_txtvw);
                Sub_mobileno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobileno_txtvw);
                Sub_billno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.billno_txtvw);
                Sub_age = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.age_txtvw);
                Itemstatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemstatus_txtvw);                    
            }
        }

        public OrdersAdapter(List<OrderModel> ordersList) {
            this.ordersModelList = ordersList;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {    
            final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.orders_based_onfilters, null);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {    
            final OrderModel MybookedordersListInfo = ordersModelList.get(position);    

            Integer order_status_id = MybookedordersListInfo.getOrderStatus();
            holder.Order_no.setText("OrderID: " + ((MybookedordersListInfo.getId() != null) ? MybookedordersListInfo.getId() : "--"));
            holder.Order_Date.setText("Date: " + ((MybookedordersListInfo.getOrderDate() != null) ? date2 : "--"));
            holder.Sub_name.setText("Name: " + ((MybookedordersListInfo.getCustomerName() != null) ? MybookedordersListInfo.getCustomerName() : "--"));
            holder.Sub_mobileno.setText("Mobile: " + ((MybookedordersListInfo.getMobile() != null) ? MybookedordersListInfo.getMobile() : "--"));
            holder.Sub_billno.setText("BillNo: " + ((MybookedordersListInfo.getBillno() != null) ? MybookedordersListInfo.getBillno() : "--"));
            holder.Sub_age.setText("Age: " + ((MybookedordersListInfo.getAge() != null) ? MybookedordersListInfo.getAge().toString() : "--"));             
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            if (ordersModelList != null) {
                return ordersModelList.size();
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the error that you are getting?

Comment: Can u plz check this issue,[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479168/procedure-for-recycler-view-used-in-fragments-for-tablayout) @Quintin Balsdon... calling retrofit in Tabactivity class and adapter class is used in FragmentActivity(same as above)...

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon